# Excel sheet exception handling

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a function and did exception handling in it. What I also did was, I created a method which identifies whether any exception has occurred in my function.

If an exception has occurred, it records a PASS/FAIL in J cell of row 2 and also details about the exception if it is a FAIL in K cell of row 2.

When I ran my code, the excel sheet was updated with a FAIL(as I made an exception to deliberately occur). But, when I opened my excel sheet, I found that J cell of row 2 contained FAIL and K cell of row 2 contained "Exception "

Ideally, I want K cell of row 2 to contain the exact text of my exception like "DivideByZeroException was found in code" Something like that.

I posted my code. Is there any mistake in it? Am I missing something?

```
public int CreateMyTask()
        {
try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking CreateTask method");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            m_taskID = taskClient.CreateTask(m_tInstance);
            Console.WriteLine("Task create successfully:ID=" + m_taskID.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            WriteResultInExcel(false, "");
            return m_taskID;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            WriteResultInExcel(true, ex.Message);
        }
}


 private void WriteResultInExcel(bool isExceptionalData, string message)
    {
        Excel.ApplicationClass excelApp = new ApplicationClass();
        Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\myexcelsheet.xls", 0, false, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
        if(isExceptionalData)
        {
            ((Range)worksheet.Cells["2", "J"]).Value2 = "FAIL";
            ((Range)worksheet.Cells["2", "K"]).Value2 = message;
        }
        else
        {
            ((Range)worksheet.Cells["2", "J"]).Value2 = "PASS";
        }
        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close(0, 0, 0);
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: If you step through the debugger, what message does the exception object contain when you are in the catch() block?

Comment: @TiesonT. it contains the message ""An error occurred during a WCF call, see inner Detail for more info!""

Comment: Does the worksheet have any formatting applied to it? I wonder if it thinks you're trying to write text into a number field...

Comment: @TiesonT.no friend...no formatting is applied to the worksheet...

Comment: Looks like you're using the Office Interop library. Is this the 2003 or 2010 version?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Text` property, rather than `Value` or `Value2`?

Comment: @TiesonT.its no use..okay, leave that..am facing a new issue now...now, nothing is getting updated within my excel sheet..donno why..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151589/excel-sheet-not-getting-updated-with-exception

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ex.GetType().Name
```

or

```
ex.ToString()
```

Perhaps if you can tell us what's in `ex.Message` and what exactly is your result in the cell, I can give a more detail answer.

Comment: ex.message contains ""An error occurred during a WCF call, see inner Detail for more info!""

Answer (score 0):

Refer this - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/197707a3-7940-4c91-ab53-15d186201135

Also make sure you have enabled this on the Behavior Service

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```

Comment: I don't think the OP really needs the exception detail - he's just trying to get the top-level message at the moment.